# Only Assigning Last Iteration to Object

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs

While attempting to initialize my new object with unique numerical values based off the current iteration of my for-loop, I noticed that only the last numerical value is being assigned. For example, if the counter of the loop is supposed to stop at 12, I expect 12 objects to be logged out from the variable, instead I will only get the twelfth iteration logged. I tried wrapping it in a closure, and still no luck. I log out the 12 objects inside the loop, no problem, but when outside of the closure, only the last iteration is available.

Edit: To give a better overview, here's my link on Heroku of my project. Basically, in my textbox, I want to enter "40" and then I capture that 40, set it to my this.state.text, use that as my control variable in my loop, and create 40 horses on screen. To save not losing the current horses on screen, I'm trying to create a new Object (StudentsNew) and then do a shallow merge.

http://aqueous-tor-94316.herokuapp.com/

```
var StudentsNew;
   for(var i = 0; i <= this.state.text; i++){
      (function(index){
           StudentsNew = { [index]:{ left: 100, top: 100 } };
      })(i); 
   }
   console.log(StudentsNew);
```

Comment: You are overriding StudentNew each iteration. Do you expect that there will be 12 StudentNew variables - why?

Comment: Are you just trying to push  the object { left: 100, top: 100 } into each index of an array?

Comment: A variable can only contain a single value. You can use [an array](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html)
 to store a list of values.

Comment: What are you expecting StudentsNew to contain when the loop ends?  It can only hold one object, unless you initialize it as an array, and then add the objects to the array with each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what you want to do:

```
var StudentsNew = {};
for(var i = 0; i <= this.state.text; i++){
  StudentsNew[i] = {left: 100, top: 100};
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(StudentsNew));
```

Output:

{"0":{"left":100,"top":100},"1":{"left":100,"top":100},"2":{"left":100,"top":100},"3":{"left":100,"top":100},"4":{"left":100,"top":100},"5":{"left":100,"top":100},"6":{"left":100,"top":100},"7":{"left":100,"top":100},"8":{"left":100,"top":100},"9":{"left":100,"top":100},"10":{"left":100,"top":100},"11":{"left":100,"top":100},"12":    {"left":100,"top":100}}

Comment: No, it has to be an object, not an array. This is only a small snippet of my project. I'm using React-DnD to do some drag and drop operations

Comment: Justin it does not log an array but an object